# Wall outlet configuration

Tags: electrical

I read everything I could on this site and others but have not found a great solution. I have 4 wall outlets in a room. I need a easy way to find out the main feed outlet as I guess each outlet is fed from the other. Like outlet (A) feeds to outlet (B), (B) to (C), etc. How do I find out which one feeds the other without disconnecting wires and see where it stops, and find the main feed outlet. One circuit breaker controls all 4. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually find the last outlet because it only has 1 set of wires, and then work backwards towards the breaker panel is often logical, there are also specialty tools that can measure voltage drop across each of the receptacles and make an educated guess at the first receptacle that has the lowest voltage drop

https://youtu.be/16KObgI44UE?t=286

Comment: Dang. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Great answer. I think I can use an electric heater on the outlets from what I see with that fancy tools and measure the voltage at each outlet. The one with the less voltage would be the last, and the one with the most the first. Thanks for the suggestion. It's a good start.